# Writing a Java class with instance parameters, retrieve parameters and print results

Tags: java

Basically, I need to create a new simple Java class which retrieves values from my forms (that I have designed as my process and is deployed as a web application), once the method in the Java class is invoked then the Java class should just simply print out the values (e.g. system.println.out...) it got from the form in a console or text file.

Create a class with some instance parameters. Print a line stating the initial values of these parameter(s).

I am new to Java and have just started few days ago but have this requirement as part of a project.

Please someone help to write this Java class.

Comment: Where the code snippet, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, tag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read some  java beginners books (or the javadoc) in order to understand the Class constructor concept in java before trying to do write something wrong.

A rough class may be like this :

```
public class myClass{
   int param1;
   int param2;

   public myClass(int firstparam, int secondparam){
     this.param1 = firstparam;
     this.param2 = secondparam;
   }
}

public static void main(){ 
    myClass c = new myClass(1,2);
    System.out.println(c.param1 + c.param2);
}
```

If you don't understand this, please learn the java basis..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a class and its constructer like:

```
public class Test {

    //a string representation that we will initialize soon
    private String text;

    //Firstly you have to instantiate your Test object and initialize your "text"
    public Test(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        //System.out.println(text);
        //You can print out this text directly using this constructor which also             
        //has System.out.println()
    }

    //You can just use this simple method to print out your text instead of using the 
    //constructor with "System.out.println"
    public void printText() {
        System.out.println(this.text);//"this" points what our Test class has
    }

}
```

While using this class is like:

```
  public class TestApp {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

          Test testObject = new Test("My Text");

          /*if you used the constructor with System.out.println, it directly prints out  
          "My Text"*/

          /*if your constructor doesn't have System.out.println, you can use our      
          printText() method //like:*/
          testObject.printText();
      }
  }
```